# nodejs: Fail to retrieve the express session attribute value when frontend calls backend node.js program

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an web application using node.js as backend and php as frontend.

My target is when the user adds one item into shopping cart, the backend program first checks if the shopping cart session attribute exists. If the session attribute "cart" exists, append it; otherwise, create it.

The problem is I cannot "persistent" store the session variable when I use php to call the application. That is, I assume after adding one item into shopping cart, a new session attribute is created. If the users add one more item into shopping cart, the existing session attribute will be used again. However, the session attribute always return the last added item if even user has added multiple items before. In other word, the session attribute can only store the last added record instead of accumulated record.

After searching from the Internet, I guess it is due to asynchronous program of node.js and the session attribute is in "memory" based?? And thus, I cannot simply apply session attribute to persistently store the session attribute under the same session. But I am not sure how can I modify the program to achieve the goal.

Could anyone advise on this issue? Thank you.

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
    secret: '123456',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.session = req.session;
  next(null, req, res);
})
```

cart.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Cart = require('../models/cart');

router.get('/addCart', function(req, res, next){
  var menuID = req.query.menuID;
  var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {});
  var menuPrice = 0;
  var menuItem = {menu_id:"", menu_price:""};

  connection.query('SELECT menuprice from menu where menuID = ?', [menuID], function (error, results, fields) {
    if( error ) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 500, "error": error, "response": null})); 

    } else  {
        menuPrice = results[0].menuprice;
        menuItem = {id:menuID, price:menuPrice};

        cart.add(menuItem, menuID);
        req.session.cart = cart;

        res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "cart": req.session.cart}));

    }});
    })
```

Comment: have you tried adding to cart with postman?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you need to identify the session somehow otherwise every request will create a new session. Imagine you have 50 users using your app in parallel and when they request your app you need to detect somehow which cart belong to which user. `express-session` stores session ID in a cookie.

When a new session is created then the server response contains the cookie with a session ID and the browser sends it in all the subsequent calls. If I understand it well you have it implemented this way: browser ----> PHP ----> node.js
Make sure that the PHP app is not scrapping the cookies.